# ScrollBar issue with StageWebView in Flash Builder Mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, stagewebview

I am developing flex mobile application and I am using the StageWebView Class to show formatted html content. The only issue I am having is that when I view my application on the mobile, I am not having any scrollbars so that I can move up or down to see the contents of my html.

Note that my html file contains formatted text, images and hyperlinks.

Is there any way to show scrollbars?

Or any other better way to display such data on my mobile, other than StageWebView?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your StageWebView has correct dimensions (width and height)?

Here a View from an app using StageWebView to display usage help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        viewActivate="openSWV(event)"
        viewDeactivate="closeSWV(event)"
        title="Help">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.popView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String id="_help">
            <![CDATA[
<html>
<body>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
</ul>


<table border=1 width=100%>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th>Blah</th><th>Blah</th><th>Blah</th><th>Blah</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>6</th><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>7</th><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<th>8</th><td>6</td><td>1*</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Blah</th><td>10</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>9</th><td>8</td><td>1*</td><td>1</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>10</th><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</i></p>

</body>
</html>
            ]]>
        </fx:String>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import flash.media.StageWebView;

            private var _swv:StageWebView;

            private function openSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                _swv = new StageWebView();
                stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);

                _swv.stage = stage;
                resizeSWV();

                _swv.loadString(_help);
            }

            private function closeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);
                if (! _swv)
                    return;
                _swv.dispose();
                _swv = null;
            }           

            private function resizeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                if (! _swv)
                    return;

                var scale:Number = scale = runtimeDPI / applicationDPI;
                // align to the right-bottom corner
                _swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(stage.stageWidth - scale * width, stage.stageHeight - scale * height, scale * width, scale * height);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

It displays scrollbars on Android, iOS and BB10 just fine...

Comment: I got the scrollbars working..thx

However I am wondering. If my html contains hyperlinks or image hyperlinks. How will the hyperlinks reckon clicking events etc.

Is using StageWebView the right solution or is there any other alternative to this? Is it possible to interact with the contents (image, links etc) of the html output.

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: Maybe you need to develop an HTML5 app and not flex mobile? :-) Actually I don't think such things are possible with `StageWebView`.

Comment: Well if there is no other way other than StageWebView, then Flex (if I can say Apache Flex SDK) seems unnappropriate for interactive mobile apps then? Just confirming..

Comment: I meant displaying too rich HTML content and reacting to clicks